# Compute $\pi_{2}(S^2 \vee S^2).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Compute $\pi_{2}(S^2 \vee S^2).$

**Hint:**
Use universal covering thm. and use Van Kampen to show it is simply connected.

Still I am unable to solve it, could anyone give me more detailed hint and the general idea of the solution.

Comment: Where is this problem from?  What is the "universal covering thm." (which does not sound like it would be relevant to this problem...)?  What tools do you have available?

Comment: This space is already simply connected hence is the universal cover of itself. Perhaps you intended the question about $\pi_2(S^2\vee S^1)$?

Comment: Frankly speaking I am lost @EricWofsey I know that I can not use cohomology as I did not take it

Comment: we are working from Hatcher@EricWofsey

Comment: @GregoryG the space you mentioned is not the space I am speaking about?

Comment: Well, this problem is solved (in a more general form) in the text of Hatcher in Example 4.26.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another quick way, using Hurewicz.

$\pi_1(S^2 \vee S^2) \cong 0$ by van Kampen. Then the Hurewicz theorem asserts that $\pi_2(S^2 \vee S^2) \cong H_2(S^2 \vee S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5):

Following [homotopy excision theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_excision_theorem) and using an exact sequence of a pair $(S^2\times S^2, S^2\vee S^2)$ you can write down an exact sequence 
$$
  0 \to \pi_3(S^2\wedge S^2)\to \pi_2(S^2\vee S^2) \to \pi_2(S^2\times S^2) \to 0
$$
Since $S^2\wedge S^2 \simeq S^4$ you have an isomorphism $\pi_2(S^2\vee S^2) \cong \pi_2(S^2\times S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: How do you get this exact sequence and why the operation between the two sphere is changed from $\wedge$ to $\vee$ to $\times.$

Comment: @Mathstupid From homotopy excision $\pi_3(S^2\times S^2, S^2\vee S^2)\cong \pi_3(S^2\times S^2/S^2\vee S^2) = \pi_3(S^2\wedge S^2).$ The exact sequence is just a part of the exact sequence of a pair $(S^2\times S^2, S^2\vee S^2),$ as I've written above.